# Trying to read an Excel file from ZipArchive with EPPlus

Tags: c#, epplus

I'm trying to read an excel file from a zip archive:

```
var excelEntry = archive.Entries.Single(entry => Regex.IsMatch(entry.FullName, @"\.xlsx\z", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase));
using (var excelPackage = new ExcelPackage(excelEntry.Open()))
{
}
```

However, I get a NotSupportedException.

```
(Exception thrown: 'System.NotSupportedException' in System.dll
Additional information: This operation is not supported.)
```

The file is a simple .xlsx without any protection.
Any ideas?

Comment: I see now that the ziparchive is on read mode, maybe something to do with ExcelPackage requiring a Read/Write stream?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was indeed due to the fact that the zip archive stream was read only, whereas the ExcelPackage only accepts read/write streams.

I made the following adjustments:

```
var entryStream = excelEntry.Open();
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
using (var excelPackage = new ExcelPackage())
{
  entryStream.CopyTo(ms);
  excelPackage.Load(ms);
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution!